# AMP split array in src bind

Tags: arrays, string, amp-html, whitelist, amp-bind

I am trying to build a binding in an amp-list. What I need to do is extract the first entry in the array. For instance my json array looks like this:

"Ids": [
    "123",
    "456"
]

The amp-binding is looking like this:
[src]="'http://any.com?id=' + {{Ids}}"

I want this to end up like:
src="http://any.com?id=123

But is looks like this without any manipulation
src="http://any.com?id=123,456

Looking at the [white listed functions](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#white-listed-functions), I wondering if I should use Array to String for this.

Comment: try using amp-mustache.

Comment: Mustache is being used to build the src. My issue is getting only one number out of the json array.

Comment: Did you try to slice your array and get only that element which you need by its index?